# WPF Binding on startup

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

In my WPF project, I have the Visibility of a Grid bound to a `bool` with a `BooleanToVisibilityConverter`:

```
<Grid ... Visibility="{Binding SelectedElement.HasError, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=BoolToVis}}">
```

However on startup the grid is always shown for a few milliseconds, even though the element/class holding the `bool` field is not even created, and after creation is defaulted to `false`.

How can I prevent the grid from showing up on startup? I tried to implement a `FallbackValue` for the binding, because the object in the path is not yet available, but setting "Visible" or "Hidden" here doesn't change anything.

Comment: How setting "Hidden" as default not work? it must be work, if not, try to use debugger and find what is causing switching visibility

Comment: Thanks, for me it works with "Collapsed" @Niewidzialny

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

Works fine with `FallbackValue=Collapsed`.